# Facebook Ads API/SDK - The global ID [xxxx] is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to get the name associated with an Ad Account. Using the API calling `/me` gets my user info no problem. Calling /me/adaccounts gets me an object with a data node that is an array of account id objects which has an id node.  I use this ID to try and get the Ad Account and I get the following error:

*The global ID [xxxx] is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.*

The code is included below, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($config['id'], $config['secret']);
    $session = new FacebookSession($accessToken);
    $api = new Api($session);
    echo '<pre>';
    $adAccountsResponse = $api->call('/me/adaccounts','GET');
    $adAccounts = $adAccountsResponse->getResponse();

    foreach($adAccounts->data as $adAccount)
    {
        $adAccountId = $adAccount->account_id;
        $adAccount = new AdAccount($adAccountId, null, $api);
        $adAccount->read(array(AdAccountFields::NAME));
        print_r($adAccount);
    }
```

I did a `print_r($api)` and it says I am using version 2 of the API.

```
[responseHeaders:protected] => Array
            (
                [http_code] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                [Last-Modified] => 2014-07-20T14:37:10+0000
                [Facebook-API-Version] => v2.0
                [ETag] => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                [Pragma] => no-cache
                [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => *
                [X-FB-Rev] => 1454522
                [Cache-Control] => private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
                [Expires] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
                [X-FB-Debug] =>  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                [Date] => Wed, 15 Oct 2014 15:10:36 GMT
                [Connection] => keep-alive
                [Content-Length] => 234
            )
```

Interesting enough when I use the Graph API Explorer switching between API version numbers using the token that I have I get the same user ID no matter what the version of the API.  So something is messed up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439917/the-global-id-is-not-allowed-please-use-the-application-specific-id-instead here is the ans.

Comment: I've looked at that.  That isn't the answer.  I am using the Facebook Approved php sdk.  Nothing in the docs explains how to get this "application specific id".  Hence asking the question.  Don't point to the first post a google search gives because that's not always the answer.  I provided code hoping someone would provide something that I could understand since I can't find it elsewhere.

Comment: May be this will guide on right path: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465196803626925/

Comment: That's a better explanation of what I am encountering.  Though it seems the v4 SDK calls 2.0 API.  I wonder if tokens are tied to an api version.

Comment: Are you calling `/<account id>` or `/act_<account id>` ? the latter is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an extremely odd error to receive as it doesn't actually relate to adaccounts.

There is however an easier way to retrieve the list of attributes you want in a single call using connections of the object AdUser:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdAccountFields;

$user = new AdUser('me');
$accounts = $user->getAdAccounts(array(AdAccountFields::NAME)));

foreach($accounts as $account) {
  echo $account->name."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This returned an object but the name field is an empty string.  Do you know if this is user definable and optional?

Comment: sure, you can do $account->name = 'some name'; $account->save();

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood my question.  I won't be manipulating the data via the API just pulling it.  I am wondering if it's an optional field for the user (in this case our client) to define in the web management took.  I figured I could define it in the API, but that's not part of what we want to do with the API.

Comment: it's not optional but it's possible to set to an empty string. It'd be extremely unusual for that to be the case however. If you call the graph directly what do you see?
http://graph.facebook.com/me/adaccounts?fields=name&access_token=<TOKEN>

Comment: It does show up as an empty string.  OK, I am going to have to program for that.  Can't display a name if the client account doesn't have one.  thanks for the help this helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the Graph API version prefix to your call:

```
$adAccountsResponse = $api->call('/v2.1/me/adaccounts','GET');
```

Comment: That gives me:

Unknown path components: /me/adaccounts

So that does not seem to work with the php sdk.

Comment: Do you use the most recent PHP SDK?

Comment: yes I am using the most recent SDK.  v4.  When I included the require for the ads-sdk it automatically required v4 and pulled that down as well.